# Estoy agregando archivos a mi repositorio de git y no me los agrega

Tags: git

Necesito ayuda, estoy trabajando en `vsc` y tengo mi carpeta hecha repositorio de git. Cuando quiero agregar los archivos modificados a la "stagin area" no me los agrega. Hago: `git add .`, y después `git status`, y me sigue apareciendo en rojo (como si no se hubiera agregado a la staging area).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `ProyectoWeb` es un submodulo? o un subtree? Nota aparte: Podrías quitar la imegan y pegar los comandos y la salida de los comandos como texto en la pregunta?

Comment: Disculpa la ignorancia pero nose que es un subtree... Tengo en escritorio una carpeta Proyecto Final python donde adentro tengo otra carpeta mi_repo_final (dentro de esa carpeta tambien tengo una carpeta .git (repositorio)) y dentro de esa carpeta (mi_repo_final) otra carpeta que es proyectoWeb (que alli tambien tengo una carpeta .git) al no saber usar bien quizas cometi el error de crear 2 repositorios en las dos carpetas. Proyectoweb es el django-admin startproject ...

Comment: $PS C:\Users\gjalo\Desktop\Proyecto final python\mi_repo_final> git add .

Comment: PS C:\Users\gjalo\Desktop\Proyecto final python\mi_repo_final> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   ProyectoWeb (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: No se como fue que llegaste a tu ambiente actual _pero_ si hay un repositorio dentro de un repositorio (como aparentemente sucede con `ProyectoWeb`), creo que es normal que git no considere que lo que esté en `ProyectoWeb` lo deba manejar el repositorio que lo incluye así que lo que ves es más o menos esperado dado el ambiente actual. **Nota al margen**: me refería a poner el texto _en la pregunta original_ y quitar la imagen.

Comment: aah bien, con que proposito? necesito solucionar el problema... si decis que git no estaria considerando lo que esta en proyecto web, como decis que puedo solucionarlo? no me permite borra las carpetas .git

Comment: Si estás en Windows y tienes un IDE abierto usando esos proyectos, es más que probable que el IDE tenga abiertos archivos dentro de los repositorios (o sea, dentro de los directorios `.git`) y tratar de borrar archivos que estás abiertos en Windows es un **no-go**. Tendrías que cerrar el IDE y ver cómo te va para borrar los directorios `.git`que **consideres** (que conste que no estoy diciendo nada con respecto a que debas borrar esto o aquello, no tengo suficientes elementos para poder decidir el mejor curso de acción sinceramente).

Comment: Con respecto a remover la imagen, el texto que vayas a poner se podría indexar para personas que tengan más o menos tu mismo problema, cosa que no se puede hacer con una imagen (aparte de no necesitar una lupa para ver lo que sale en el terminal)